# how to set image for buttons and hover effect for images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-events

How to set image for button and hover effect for prev and next button images? I do not know how to set image for button, and hover effect for prev and next button images. I need image opacity 0.1 also image button hover disabled,on disabled condition.and image opacity 0.5 on enabled condition also hover effect 0.5.   Please help me. See example code: http://jsfiddle.net/YHXFp/50/

html

```
<div id="prevnexts">
    <button class="navButs" id="prevs">Prev</button>
    <button class="navButs" id="nexts">Next</button>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cnt = 1;
    var maxLinkss = 5;
    $("#prevs").attr("disabled","disabled");
    $("#nexts").attr("enabled","enabled");   

    $(".navButs").click(function(){
        
        if (this.id=="nexts") {
            cnt++;  
            console.log(" + ",cnt);  
        } else {
            cnt--;
            console.log(" - ",cnt);  
        }
        
        if (cnt<0) cnt=0;
        
        if (cnt==maxLinkss-1) {
            $("#nexts").attr("disabled","disabled");
        } else {
            $("#nexts").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        
        if (cnt==1) {
            $("#prevs").attr("disabled","disabled");
        } else {
            $("#prevs").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
button#nexts{
    background:url(your_image_url) no-repeat;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
button#prevs{
    background:url(your_image_url) no-repeat;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

button#nexts:hover, button#prevs:hover{
    opacity:.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/YHXFp/37/)
​

Comment: also i need disabled and enabled contition.button image totally disabled also hover on disabled condition.

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YHXFp/44/), changes have been made in `jQuery` and `css` both.

Comment: wow.your script is very nice.it is working perfectly.but if i click the next button after disabled the count increase unlimited.why?see:http://jsfiddle.net/YHXFp/64/

Comment: [Check this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YHXFp/82/) and let me know if it's alright.

Answer (score 0):

Putting images is not a good way aas its slows down the loading of the web page. CSS is better. Here's the CSS code and the [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YHXFp/36/)
(I've chosen arbitrarily colors. Choose your desired colors ). 
In case of images just replace `background-color` with `background-image:url(www.example.com/myimage.png)`.

```
#prevs{
    background-color:#666;
    color:#000;
}
#prevs:hover{
    background-color:#004534;
}
#prevs:active{
    background-color:red;
}
#nexts{
    background-color:#999;
    color:#000;
}
#nexts:hover{
    background-color:#00fcbe;
}
#nexts:active{
    background-color:blue;
}
```